# SQL Count Distinct over Rolling Window on Timestamp

Tags: sql, mysql, count, distinct, window-functions

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerName) over(
            ORDER BY OrderTimestamp 
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 2 hour PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
        ) AS count_per_time
FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerName IS NOT null
AND CustomerName != ''
```

but it doesn't work because DISTINCT is not allowed with OVER clause. Could anyone help me how to solve it, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this can be solved with window functions.

There is an emulation technique that uses a substraction of `dense_rank`s, but the latter does not support window frame specifications (ie: the `range` / `rows` syntax in your original code). Well, to be precise, it actually allows the syntax, but silently ignores it : so it still operates over the whole partition. This is explained in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html):

> Standard SQL specifies that window functions that operate on the entire partition should have no frame clause. MySQL permits a frame clause for such functions but ignores it. **These functions use the entire partition even if a frame is specified**:
>
> ```
> CUME_DIST()
> DENSE_RANK()
> LAG()
> LEAD()
> NTILE()
> PERCENT_RANK()
> RANK()
> ROW_NUMBER()
> ```

It seems like the only option left is a subquery:

```
SELECT o.*,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o1.CustomerName) 
        FROM Orders o1
        WHERE o1.CustomerName != ''
        WHERE o1.OrderTimestamp BETWEEN o.OrderTimestamp - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AND o.OrderTimestamp
    ) AS count_per_time
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.CustomerName IS NOT null and o.CustomerName != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `DENSE_RANK()`, with `PARTITION BY` the grouped columns, and `ORDER BY` both `ASC` and `DESC` on the columns to count:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() over(
            PARTITION BY CustomerName 
            ORDER BY OrderTimestamp ASC
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 2 hour PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
        ) +
        DENSE_RANK() over(
            PARTITION BY CustomerName 
            ORDER BY OrderTimestamp DESC
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 2 hour PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
        ) - 1
        AS count_per_time
FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerName IS NOT null
AND CustomerName != ''
```

Comment: i don't know why the result is wrong :(

Comment: `dense_rank` operates over the whole partition and ignores `range`/`rows` frames, even if you specify it.